# What is meant by "offence can scarcely be visited on the quantity"

Tags: meaning-in-context, archaicisms

The full text is below.

> "Friend, be not tedious," said the Rajah of Travancore to a Christian
> missionary, in the sixteenth century, "remember life is short." I have
> endeavoured to pay due attention to this admirable advice; and if what
> I have written be wearisome, **the offence can scarcely be visited on
> the quantity.**

The Bungalow and The Tent or a Visit to Ceylon (1854) by Edward Sullivan, pg. viii

What does it mean by "the offence can scarcely be visited on the quantity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visit%20on%2Fupon) records ***visit on/upon*** as a phrasal verb:

> formal + old-fashioned
> : to punish (someone) with (something)
>
> - The Lord ***visited*** a plague ***upon*** the city.

The author receives the advice not to be tedious by expressing things in too many boring words - life is short. He did follow the advice, so the sentence:

> The offence can scarcely be ***visited on*** the quantity.

means that although what the author has written may be wearisome, it is not because of quantity (of words). The offence of being tedious cannot be inflicted on the quantity of words he used, but rather on the content of the words or on something else.

[FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/visit+on) defines the phrase as meaning:

> To inflict something punishing or burdensome on someone or something. *Used chiefly in the passive*:
>
> - A plague was visited on the village.

Comment: I disagree with this interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

*Visited* means *examined* here:

> **visit**, *v.*
>
> **II. 9. a.** To go to look at (†or explore); to inspect or examine; to look into or see to (something); in later use *esp.* to examine
> (vessels, goods, baggage, etc.) officially.
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

This sense might be more easily understood if we compare the more modern and familiar *revisit*:

> **revisit**, *v.*
>
> **1. c.** *transitive*. *figurative* and in figurative context. To return to (a subject, period, etc.) previously examined; to take a
> fresh or further look at; *spec.* to consider (a question, situation,
> or problem) again, or from a different perspective.
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

So, to paraphrase:

> *If what I have written be wearisome, the offence [of being wearisome] can’t be examined [based] on the quantity [of words] (because I haven’t used many words).*